# How to do a heavy task in Flutter Web without blocking the UI?

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf-generation

I have to generate a pdf with a line chart that is displayed on the screen. Right now I use the following code to capture an image of the chart, print it to a pdf and then open the pdf on a new Tab.

```
printChart() async {
    Future<Uint8List> captureWidgetToImage(GlobalKey key) async {
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = key.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderRepaintBoundary;
      ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0); // Adjust the pixelRatio as needed
      ByteData? byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
      return byteData!.buffer.asUint8List();
    }

    Future<Uint8List> generatePDF(Uint8List imageBytes) async {
      final pdf = pw.Document();
      pdf.addPage(
        pw.Page(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4.landscape,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Image(pw.MemoryImage(imageBytes));
          },
        ),
      );

      return await pdf.save();
    }

    Uint8List imageBytes = await captureWidgetToImage(_chartKey);
    final Uint8List pdfData = await compute(generatePDF, imageBytes);

    final blob = html.Blob([pdfData], 'application/pdf');
    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);
    html.window.open(url, '_blank');
}
```

But the image capturing process and the pdf generation takes time. Image capturing takes approximately 1.5 sec while the pdf generation can take upto 20 sec. And while this process is running, the UI is freezed.

I tried to look into **compute**, but then realized that it is not working on flutter-web. What is the flutter-web version to handle heavy tasks?